# LightGBM: Continued Training Sklearn Interface

Tags: scikit-learn, lightgbm

I'm trying to figure out how to use the LightGBM Sklearn interface for continued training of a classifier. The documentation makes it clear that I need to supply an "init_score" input to the fit method. This is supposed to be an array-like of shape [n_samples], so at the level of rows. Unfortunately, the documentation does not explain how to compute that init_score from the previously fit tree. There are no obvious methods for computing this score that I can see. For example, the predict method produces labels by default, and if I ask for raw_scores, I get an ndarray of shape [n_samples, n_labels]. I've gone through the LightGBM code, and I don't see how to create an appropriate value for init_score. Would someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

Here is code that worked for me.

```
X_b, X_test_b, y_b, y_test_b = train_test_split(X,y)
d_train = lgb.Dataset(X_b, label=y_b)

params = {}
params['learning_rate'] = 0.03
params['boosting_type'] = 'gbdt'
params['objective'] = 'regression'
<keep going...>

lg_model = lgb.train(params, d_train, 27500)
y_pred = lg_model.predict(X_test_b)
```

Comment: Thank you for this prompt answer, @CJW. Unfortunately, it shows how to do this with only the _Python_ API commands instead of the [Sklearn API](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Python-API.html#scikit-learn-api), and I need the information for latter.